# Частичное представление

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

В Home контроллере есть два метода:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{   
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    } 

    //[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Load()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
}
```

Я пытаюсь асинхронно загрузить частичное представление из метода `Load`. Делаю я так:

```
<button class="btn btn-default loadbook" type="submit">
    @Ajax.ActionLink("ClickMe","Load", new AjaxOptions(){UpdateTargetId="di"})
</button>
```

но он обновляет страницу и грузит его на новой странице.
В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не работало, пока не установил пакет из *NuGet* для *Ajax* - 
`Microsoft.JQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax`

Answer (score 3):

У вас тип кнопки `submit`, поэтому её нажатие вызывает обновление страницы, смените его на `button`

Comment: не решает проблему.Он все равно переходит на то представление что возвращает метод Load.Я же хочу что бы представление что возвращает метод Load погрузился в текущее представление на котором расположена эта кнопка.Поэтому оно и сделано частичным представлением.